# Sum of $k$, $k$ - gonal numbers related to Fermat's Polygonal Number Theorem.

Tags: number-theory

How can you check that, whether there is a possibility of expressing a positive integer $m$ as a sum of $k$, $k$ - gonal numbers given that the sum of corresponding $k-1$, $k-1$ - gonal numbers is $m$?  
As an example is there any possibility of expressing a positive integer m as a sum of p th square number, q th square number and r th square number with another square number given that m is sum of p th triangle number, q th triangle number and r th triangle number.

Here is how I have tried it for $k = 4$

Let $u(k,n)$ be the $n$th $k$-gonal number.
Let $m = u(3,p)+u(3,q)+u(3,r) \hspace{30pt}(A)$
By the relationship, 
$u(k,n)=u(k-1,n)+u(3,n-1)$, it can be deduced that,
$u(3,p)=u(4,p)-u(3,p-1)$\
$u(3,q)=u(4,q)-u(3,q-1)$
$u(3,r)=u(4,r)-u(3,r-1)$
By substituting to the equation $A$,
$m = u(4,p)+u(4,q)+u(4,r)-\{u(3,p-1)+ u(3,q-1) + u(3,r-1) \}$ 
$u(4,p),u(4,q),u(4,r)$ are corresponding $4$-gonal numbers of $u(3,p),u(3,q),u(3,r)$, $3-$gonal numbers. 
Now to write $m$ as sum of $4$, $4$-gonal numbers $\{u(3,p-1)+ u(3,q-1) + u(3,r-1) \}$ must be a negative $4$ -gonal number or zero.  
 This sum can not be negative because triangle numbers are not negative. But if all triangle numbers are zero this sum can be zero and u(3,p),u(3,q),u(3,r) all equal to 1.
Now m = 1+1+1=3  
This can be written as m = 1+1+1+0   
Here you have m as the sum of corresponding 4- gonal numbers with another 4 - gonal number. Is this the only way you can satisfy the given condition?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @community- Actually I asked my question again at the end of the example described in the question because I I thought it might be not clear in my question part. My question is how can you prove the described issue is impossible, according to what I obtained it seems like what I am suggesting here is correct because of the requirement of negative square number for the above mentioned sum of three triangle numbers. Am I correct ?

Comment: @community- I have edited the title and the question to give better interpretation. Hope now you can understand the issue.

Comment: I suggest you give a numerical example to make things clear.

Comment: @user25406- I extended my example including equal k- gonal numbers.